# Using index as key for React Components?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm rendering a list in my react app where:

- Only new elements will be appended to the end of the list.
- Every time an element is removed, it will only be the last element.

Given these conditions as well as not having the intention to reorder elements in any way. Can I use the index as the `key` prop without having any problem?

Comment: Whilst you can  the only considerations you might take into account are 1. Are you working on a team that may ignore or not be aware of your conditions and 2. that you're likely to never change the functionality at a later day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is!

You can read what React docs says in here: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

The main is this: **We don’t recommend using indexes for keys if the order of items may change. T**

You can also check this article: https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318

According to it, if you meet this conditions:

1. the list and items are static – they are not computed and do not change;
2. the items in the list have no ids
3. the list is never reordered or filtered.

You should be good to go.